# For any positive integer $n$, evaluate $\sum^{n}_{k=0}\frac{2^{k}}{k!\left(n-k\right)!}$.

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification

For any positive integer $n$ evaluate

$$\sum^{n}_{k=0}\frac{2^{k}}{k!\left(n-k\right)!}$$

---

My work so far:

I feel that at this point a question like this should be a little easier, but so far I am stumped. I have tried this:

$$\sum^{n}_{k=0}\frac{2^{k}}{k!\left(n-k\right)!}=\frac{3^n}{n!}$$.

First note that $$3^{n}= \sum^{n}_{k=0}{ n \choose k}2^k $$

so, $$\frac{3^n}{n!}=\frac{\sum^{n}_{k=0}{ n \choose k}2^k}{n!}=\frac{\frac{n!}{k!\left(n-k\right)!}2^{k}}{n!}=\frac{2^{k}}{k!\left(n-k\right)!}$$

which concludes the proof.

Does this look okay? Thanks for any input.

Comment: There are some $\sum$s missing in in the last equation, otherwise it is correct.

Comment: The way you write, it is not clear what you know;  what is   $ \sum^{n}_{k=0}{ n \choose k}x^k \; \; ? \; \; \;$

Comment: @WillJagy I believe it is $\left(1+x\right)^n$.

Comment: It is. How does that tell us that $3^{n}= \sum^{n}_{k=0}{ n \choose k}2^k \; \; ? \; \; $

Comment: @WillJagy by using $\left(1+2\right)^n$?

Comment: yes.................suggest you work that in to make a more readable version.

Comment: Okay I can do that! Or I can at least try to do that. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your answer is correct, but you forgot the summation sign in the last two equalities. We have

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{2^k}{k!(n-k)!}=\frac{1}{n!}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}2^k=\frac{1}{n!}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\dbinom{n}{k}2^{k}=\frac{3^n}{n!}$$

by the binomial theorem.